# Master page concept in Html5?

Tags: html, master-pages

I am doing a project based on html 5 controls.All pages in my project having same header and footer. I want to apply master page concept just like in asp .net.Is it possible?If possible please tell me how to do this?

Comment: If you're using ASP.Net to generate your HTML5 you can still use ASP.Net master pages.

Comment: ya thank you for reply while i am adding option "add content page" to master page than it's automatically adding .aspx page without asking any options how to add html page?

Comment: You don't need to add an HTML page, the point of the ASPX is to generate HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can find best solution from link bellow.

[Master Page Concept in HTML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114458/Master-Pages-using-HTML-and-JavaScript)

I hope it helped.